# DateObject ambiguous string interpretation?

Tags: string-manipulation, date-and-time

I try to enter the following input, but receive an error message:

```
DateObject["12/1/2016", DateFormat -> {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}]
```

[image]

despite having specified the date format explicitly, Mathematica is complaining about ambiguity of day and month ordering. I presume there is something wrong with the syntax I use. How should I be entering this command properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got `DateFormat` option the wrong way around: it controls output, not input.

What you want to do is actually the following (with day calendar granularity):

```
DateObject[{"12/1/2016", {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}}, "Day"]
```